# Why should people ever use a single insertion method over a bulk insertion method?

Tags: mongodb, rest, document-store

I'm working with a MongoDB database for a project, and I'm making some abstractions for interacting with it. MongoDB exposes the following methods for collections:

- [insertOne](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/)
- [insertMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.insertMany)

In terms of implementation, it's my understanding that the `insertMany` operation outperforms the `inertOne` operation, so the former section of code is prefered over the latter:

```
entries: list[object] = ...

# slower implementation
for entry in entries:
  collection.insert_one(entry)

# faster implementation
collection.insert_many(entries)
```

I've been writing some wrapping interfaces, though they're basically just a few lines in addition to the code above, so I'll leave those details out. But here, my question is, outside of coding conventions and readability, do I have any incentive to use the single insertion interface if I can just do the following?

```
# put a single entry into a list and add it to the collection using the batch method
collection.insert_many([entry])
```

Comment: If you just want to insert a single item…!? Yes, it’s just a convenient abstraction over inserting one item using the bulk method…

Answer (score 0):

`insertOne` is marginally faster than `insertMany` at inserting a single document (in my very limit testing around 4-5% faster) - so in the case where you're inserting exactly one document, you should use `insertOne` - in the case where you're inserting many documents, you should use `insertMany`.

<s>A second consideration is that `insertMany` will succeed or fail atomically - in most situations this is probably desirable, but if (for whatever reason) you expect some of your inserts to fail, but still want the rest to succeed, you'd want to use `insertOne` in a loop, with a try/catch.</s>

^^ I now realise this portion of the answer was incorrect.

Comment: I don't believe your claim about atomicity of `insertMany` is true. See [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#error-handling) which mentions "_If an error is encountered, the number of successful write operations are displayed instead of a list of inserted `_ids`._"

Comment: Ah, I see now that I'm wrong (I misread the error message I got) - I'll edit my answer